# What does ellipsis at end of .clang-format mean?

Tags: clang-format

When running:

```
$ clang-format -style=Google -dump-config > .clang-format
```

The file is appended by a ellipsis (`...`).

```
TabWidth:        8
UseTab:          Never
...
```

Does it have any significance?  Can I delete it?  Someone is asking what it means in a code review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html says:

> The .clang-format file uses YAML format

http://www.yaml.org/refcard.html says:

> '...': Document terminator.

Some more from http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html:

> YAML uses three dashes (“---”) to separate directives from document
>   content. This also serves to signal the start of a document if no
>   directives are present. Three dots ( “...”) indicate the end of a
>   document without starting a new one, for use in communication
>   channels.